# How can I locate data ranges that fail to refresh in Excel that aren't listed in the connections list?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large workbook with several web and file connections. I have several macros that I run to update different sequences of these connections, the code is simply in the form:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("XMLConnect3").Refresh
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("XMLConnect4").Refresh
```

When this code runs I get 4 pop ups for every refresh attempt that is in the macro,

1. "The following data range failed to refresh: XMLConnect"
2. "The following data range failed to refresh: XMLConnect1"
3. "The following data range failed to refresh: XMLConnect2"
4. "The following data range failed to refresh: Table1"

I can click Ok on each one and the data refreshes normally. If I manually fresh my connections, these pop ups do not show, only when VBA executes Connections.Refresh does this happen.

In my connections list, there is no XMLConnect, XMLConnect1, or XMLConnect2. I used to have XML-web connections with those names but have since deleted them. I searched through all of my VBA code and looked in my Names list, I can't find any reference to them.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

XML maps are handled separately from their web connections and can be managed from the XML group in the developer tab.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/delete-xml-map-information-from-a-workbook-f3d9ef9f-5cbf-4964-b924-611959d53783

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all collections and refresh them:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim conns As Connections

    Set conns = ThisWorkbook.Connections

    For cnt = 1 To conns.Count
        Debug.Print conns.Item(cnt).Name
        conns.Item(cnt).Refresh
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

The line `Debug.Print conns.Item(cnt).Name` prints the name of the connection. The other connection properties and methods, which are easily available:

[image]

And if you have more than one range per connection, a nested loop is quite ok:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim cnt2 As Long
    Dim conns As Connections

    Set conns = ThisWorkbook.Connections

    For cnt = 1 To conns.Count
        Debug.Print conns.Item(cnt).Name

        For cnt2 = 1 To conns.Item(cnt).Ranges.Count
            Debug.Print conns.Item(cnt).Ranges.Item(cnt2).Address
        Next cnt2

        conns.Item(cnt).Refresh
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful information to have. I actually figured it out just now. I went into the Map sources under the developer tab and deleted the XML Maps from the list.